# NSLog() vs printf() when printing C string (UTF-8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, printf, nslog

I have noticed that if I try to print the byte array containing the representation of a string in UTF-8, using the format specifier "%s", `printf()` gets it right but `NSLog()` gets it garbled (i.e., each byte printed as-is, so for example "¥" gets printed as the 2 characters: "¬•").
This is curious, because I always thought that `NSLog()` is just `printf()`, plus:

1. The first parameter (the 'format') is an Objective-C string, not a C
   string (hence the "@").
2. The timestamp and app name prepended.
3. The newline automatically added at the end.
4. The ability to print Objective-C objects (using the format "%@").

My code:

```
NSString* string; 

// (...fill string with unicode string...)

const char* stringBytes = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];

NSUInteger stringByteLength = [string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
stringByteLength += 1; // add room for '\0' terminator

char* buffer = calloc(sizeof(char), stringByteLength);

memcpy(buffer, stringBytes, stringByteLength);

NSLog(@"Buffer after copy: %s", buffer);
// (renders ascii, no matter what)

printf("Buffer after copy: %s\n", buffer);
// (renders correctly, e.g. japanese text)
```

Somehow, it looks as if `printf()` is "smarter" than `NSLog()`. Does anyone know the underlying cause, and if this feature is documented anywhere? (Couldn't find)

Comment: Of course, the practical solution would be to just `NSLog` an UTF8 string as `NSString`, **not** as a C string. But in this particular case, I wanted to check that the `char` buffer had been copied right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLog()` and `stringWithFormat:` seem to expect the string for `%s`
in the "system encoding" (for example "Mac Roman" on my computer):

```
NSString *string = @"¥";
NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
const char* stringBytes = [string cStringUsingEncoding:enc];
NSString *log = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", stringBytes];
NSLog(@"%@", log);

// Output: ¥
```

Of course this will fail if some characters are not representable in the system encoding. I could not find an official documentation for this behavior, but one can see that using `%s` in `stringWithFormat:` or `NSLog()` does not reliably work with arbitrary UTF-8 strings.

If you want to check the contents of a `char` buffer containing an UTF-8 string, then
this would work with arbitrary characters (using the boxed expression syntax to create an `NSString` from a UTF-8 string):

```
NSLog(@"%@", @(utf8Buffer));
```

Comment: Oh, neat trick... I didn't know that syntax. Kind of like @(1), @[a, b, c], @{@"key":value}, etc.

Comment: BTW I was testing on iOS device; haven't tried on the Mac yet.