# How to format localised strings in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization, string-formatting

I am learning to localise my app to Simplified Chinese. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) on how to do this.

Because the tutorial is based on Obj-C, formatted strings can be written like this:

```
"Yesterday you sold %@ apps" = "Ayer le vendi&oacute; %@ aplicaciones";
```

"You like?" = "~Es bueno?~";

But I am using Swift. And in Swift I don't think you can use `%@` to indicate that there is something to be placed there. We have string interpolation right?

My app is kind of related to maths. And I want to display which input(s) is used to compute the result in a detailed label of a table view cell. For example

```
--------------
1234.5678
From x, y <---- Here is the detailed label
--------------
```

Here, `From x, y` means "The result is computed from x and y". I want to translate this to Chinese:

```
从 x, y 得出
```

Before, I can just use this:

```
"From \(someVariable)"
```

with the strings file:

```
"From" = "从 得出";
```

And this is how I would use it in code

```
"\(NSLocalizedString("From", comment: "")) \(someVariable)"
```

But if this were used in the Chinese version, the final string will be like this:

```
"从 得出 x, y"
```

I mean I can put the `从` and `得出` in two different entries in the strings file. But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You *can* use `%@` in Swift's `String(format:...)`, it can be substituted
by a Swift `String` or any instance of a `NSObject` subclass.
For example, if the Localizable.strings file contains the definition

```
"From %@, %@" = "从 %@, %@ 得出";
```

then

```
let x = 1.2
let y = 2.4
let text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("From %@, %@", comment: ""), "\(x)", "\(y)")
// Or alternatively:
let text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("From %@, %@", comment: ""), NSNumber(double: x), NSNumber(double: y))
```

produces "从 1.2, 2.4 得出". Another option would be to use the
`%f` format for double floating point numbers:

```
"From %f, %f" = "从 %f, %f 得出";
```

with

```
let text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("From %f, %f", comment: ""), x, y)
```

See [Niklas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389291/1187415)
for an even better solution which localizes the number representation 
as well.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the order of the parameters or insert a single parameter multiple times? In some languages the insertion order might be reversed. Android allows this by using `%1` and `%2` before the format specifier.

Comment: Is using `%@` better than `%s` (for strings)?

Comment: @Suragch: There are encoding problems with `%s`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672885 for an example. – I *think* that positional parameters like `%1$s` work here as well.

Comment: This code won’t localize the numbers themselves — for example in German they use periods for commas and vice-versa, and in Arabic their digits are different codepoints. Use String.localizedStringWithFormat() or String(format: "%f", locale: Locale.current, number) instead.

Comment: @WilShipley: You are completely right. Perhaps that method did not exist then or I did not think about it. I still think that I answered the question *"I don't think you can use %@ to indicate that there is something to be placed there"*, but I have added a link to the better solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I didn’t know about the other two methods but someone from that AppKit team pointed them out to me. So hopefully we can spread the word.

Comment: I am literally suprised         

"You have successfully checked-in to %@ %@" =  "％@ ％@ のチェックインが完了しました";

let translatedText = NSLocalizedString("You have successfully checked-in to %@ %@",  comment: "")

let checkInMessage = String.localizedStringWithFormat(translatedText, spaceTypeName.localizedText(), spaceName)

The above is not working…can someone help

Answer (score 62):

From [WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/401/):

```
let format = NSLocalizedString("%d popular languages", comment:"Number of popular languages")
label.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, popularLanguages.count)
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer because String.localizedStringWithFormat(_, ...) will localize the actual digits of the numbers (and swap commas and periods for German, for example), and String(format:...) will not. You can also use `String(format: "%f", locale: Locale.current, number)`.

Comment: what if the variables to be substituted are in CVarArg?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift localize a string**

One more simple example

```
let changeable = "something"
let result = String(format: NSLocalizedString("stringId", comment: ""), arguments: [changeable]) // Hello World and something
```

localizable.strings with

```
"stringId" = "Hello World and %@";
```

- `comment` parameter doesn't have effect on result and is used for translators and by `genstrings` code-gen as comment

Answer (score 3):

New in iOS 15 and macOS Monterey you can use the new refined method for String.

```
String(localized: "From \(x), \(y)", comment: "The result is computed from x and y")
```

They did a lot of updates in 2021 for localization with Xcode.  Check this video from WWDC21 for more info.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10221/

Answer (score -5):

In objective C, if we want to get strings added at runtime as below

***John Appleseed*** is the name

**YourLocalizable.strings**

```
"theStringToDisplay" = "%@ is the name";
```

**ViewController.m**

```
NSString *username = @"John Appleseed";
NSString *messageBeforeFormat = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"theStringToDisplay", @"YourLocalizable", nil);
NSString *messageAfterFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:messageBeforeFormat, username ];

self.yourLabel.text = messageAfterFormat;
```

Further explanation in this nice post

https://www.oneskyapp.com/academy/learn-ios-localization/2-format-strings-plurals/