# Swift localization with possessive

Tags: ios, swift, localization, locale

I'm dabbling with localization in Swift. It's been pretty straightforward until I have to deal with possessive.

Say I have these phrases in English:

`Carol's car is red.`
`Kris' car is red.`

In French, they would be

`La voiture de Carol est rouge`
`La voiture de Kris est rouge`

How would I set up my `Localizable.strings (French)` file? I'd imagine it's something like:

`"key" = "La voiture de %@ est rouge";`

But this doesn't really work.

Comment: What exactly does "not work"? Do you use NSLocalizedString and String.localizedStringWithFormat? – I assume that the real problem is not french but english, where you have to append `'`  or `'s`.

Comment: Sorry, let's forget about the English portion. What I'm looking for is a way to define some dynamic content my `strings` file. I'd like to to put `Carol` and `Kris` into my localized strings.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/35316655/1187415.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace text with you required value. I have just using your flow of questions, so answer is same it is.

First create your localized string as follow:

```
"key" = "La voiture de #name# est rouge";
```

Then, when you required your string. i.e

```
let strFrench = Localizable.strings(French)
```

Localizable.strings(French), this is you are assuming, so I have wrote this.

Now replace name with your dynamic value as follow:

```
let str = strFrench.replacingOccurrences(of: “#name#”, with: “YourString”)
```

I hope this will work for you. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method..
First you declare language bundle globally like as below

```
var languageBundle:Bundle?
```

then you set path for your language ,

```
if let path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Fr", ofType: "lproj") {
languageBundle =  Bundle(path: path)
} else {
languageBundle = Bundle(path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")!)
}
```

then you  assign the key name to your label

```
labelTerms.text = ((languageBundle?.localizedString(forKey: "labelAcceptTerms", value: "", table: nil) as String!))
```

Thats all!!

Before you proceed please confirm you followed below steps for creating localized string file

Select project  —> Select Use base Internationalization — > add language —> Goto storyboard and add select the checkbox (New languages added) — > add a string file localized.string —> add list of strings in that --> Use the key name  .localizedString(forKey:"addyourkeyname"