# Using a pluralized string and a number formatter at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, localization, printf

I want to show a localized string in iOS that supports the following outputs:

> 1 mile
>
> 1.5 miles
>
> 2 miles
>
> 1,5 miles

I can use a `.stringsdict` file to make the pluralization work in a way that is localizable. However, I want the number passed in to have a decimal part and I only want to show 0 or 1 decimal places. Furthermore, the number should be formatted based on locale (i.e. show the correct decimal separator).

It occurs to me the solution may take one of two forms, but I can't get either working:

1. pass in a number representation to `stringsdict` alongside a string representation
2. format the number inside the `stringsdict` using the IEEE printf specification

Comment: Will you localise the distance unit too?

Comment: Maybe in the future, but right now that's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeasurementFormatter` is exactly made for this kind of thing. You can use:

```
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .long
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
let string = formatter.string(from: Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: UnitLength.miles))
```

`MeasurementFormatter` will handle all the plural and localisation for you.

If you only want to localise the number, but not the unit, you can set the `formatter.locale` to an English locale, and set `formatter.numberFormatter.locale` to the local locale:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
formatter.numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
```

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful, and answers the question as it was asked. However, the thing that I missed out is that it's part of a longer string, so I need to go through `stringsdict` anyway - the pluralization might affect some other part of the string in some languages.

Comment: @ganzogo You could use a format string in your string dict, such as `"This road is %@ long!"` And then you would use the `String(format:_:)` initialiser to create your localised string. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316655/how-to-format-localised-strings-in-swift). (Hopefully I understood correctly...)

Comment: I think that is the solution I posted below, right? The reason that feels hacky is that you end up passing in a number version and a string version of the distance into `stringsdict`.

Comment: @ganzogo Well, if you use `MeasurementFormatter`, you get the whole string "1.5 miles". So you will only put _one_ thing into the arguments of `String(format:_:)`, like so: `String(format: NSLocalisedString("This road is %@ long!", comment: ""), arguments: [string])`. Plus, you don't need to hardcode the plural forms yourself.

Comment: Agreed - `MeasurementFormatter` makes it somewhat neater, but I would still need to pass in the number value so that the whole string can be translated taking into account the pluralization - pluralization will affect more than just one word in the sentence in some languages.

Comment: @ganzogo I know that happens with nouns, but measurements as well? I learned something new today! What language does that?

Comment: Hmmm - maybe it doesn't. But I don't see why not. In this case, "mile" is a noun and so behaves just like any other noun, as far as I know. Anway, I will accept your answer, because it is correct for what I asked. My actual solution is closer to what I posted for now though.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I actually got (1) working in the end, but it feels kind of hacky, so if anyone knows a better answer, I would still like to hear it.

```
let miles: Double = 1.5

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
let milesString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: miles))!

let formatString = NSLocalizedString("key", comment: "")
let string = String(format: formatString, arguments: [miles, milesString])
```

And the `stringsdict` looks like:

```
<dict>
        <key>key</key>
        <dict>
                <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
                <string>%1$#@miles@</string>
                <key>miles</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                        <string>f</string>
                        <key>one</key>
                        <string>1 mile</string>
                        <key>other</key>
                        <string>%2$@ miles</string>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</dict>
```